# Date sorting Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, date

Problem with sorting date. Sorting works by hours not by all date:
console.log

- 8. apr. 2022 16.54.32
- 26. jan. 2022 12.57.16
- 18. aug. 2022 10.52.22
- 8. apr. 2022 16.54.32

```
 announceSortChange(sortState: Sort) {

        this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
          console.log(item.timeStamp)
          switch (property) {
    
            case 'time':
               return item.time;
              break;
       
            default:
              return item[property];
          }
        };
       
      
        ///this code from table whre table is:
    
      getColumns() {
        return [
          {
            key: 'time',
            getValue: element => element.time,
            title: $localize`:|Column:Date`,
          }}
    
    export interface Task {   id: number;   time: string; }

table is reusable and self-adjusts to the data

I put something like that: 
     return item.time = new Date(item[property]).getTime();
 and when I press sort In table I have: NaN
```

Comment: technical details which provided is not suffice to answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

[Angular 6 Sort Array of object by Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51867404/angular-6-sort-array-of-object-by-date)

https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-sort-array-of-objects-by-date

I suggest making Date Objects or ISO Strings and comparing them. You can also use Libraries like MomentJS